# How to POST to database through URL

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm writing a web application in Spring/Hibernate that handles basic voting functionality. I want to have a link to /vote/{gameId} which will add that vote to the database for that specific ID. I'm really at a loss as for how to accomplish this though. Here's what I've tried in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/vote/{gameId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addVote(@PathVariable("gameId")
Integer gameId) {

    Vote vote = new Vote();
    vote.setGameId(gameId);

    voteService.addVote(vote);
    return "redirect:/games/wanted.html";
}
```

Here's where the link shows up in a jsp:

```
<c:if test="${!empty games}">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Game Title</th>
            <th>Votes</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${games}" var="game">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${game.title}"/></td>
                <td>Placeholder</td>
                <td><a href="vote/${game.id}">Vote!</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

When I try this though I just get a 404 error. Any insight would be great.

Comment: If it is a link... it should be a GET... no a POST... if you want to use POST... you need to make a form submit...

Comment: Also, if it is going to cause a change in the server, it should stay as a POST (but again, it should be invoked either by form submit... or by ajax call, not a link).

Comment: Well... I think I want a POST. It's a post to add things to the database, right? How would I then formulate a form submit that just submits {game.id}?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you [make a post call](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php) with plain Javascript:

```
var url = "vote";
var params = "id=1";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

You need to call this in the onclick of your link.

On the other hand it is a lot easier if, for example, you use [the jQuery Javascript library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

For your particular case it would be something like:

```
$.post("vote", { id: "1" } );
```

Or the full jQuery answer (remember to replace #linkid with the id of you  tag):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  //this runs on page load
  // Handler for .ready() called.

   $('#linkid').click(function(event) {  //this finds your <a> and sets the onclick, you can also search by css class by type of tag
     $.post("vote", { id: "1" } );
       return false; //this is important so that the link is not followed
    });

});
```